# using try to set the condition of a if in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement, try-catch

I use `try` to avoid a `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` error while going through a list of files. It does what I expect from it:

```
>> try strcmp(listFiles(6).name(1:9), 'file_name') , catch false, end

ans =

     1

>> try strcmp(listFiles(5).name(1:9), 'file_name')  , catch false, end

ans =

     0
```

However, if I want to use it inside a `if` as a condition as follow:

```
path = 'folder';
listFiles = dir(path);

for i = 1:length(listFiles)
    if (try strcmp(listFiles(i).name(1:9), 'file_name')  , catch false, end)
        [...]
    end
end
```

it return the following error `invalid used of a reserved word`.

Is there a method to force it inside or I have to use a independent variable?

Comment: Do the `try` first `try s=strcmp(...), catch ... end` then do your `if`, `if s, ..., end`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I end up doing, is there any way to avoid this independent variable?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to avoid the extra variable?

Comment: I just want to make it minimalistic. It is more for me to know if I can use this method later for other situation as well.

Comment: What causes the error, the `name(1:9)`? Why not `name(1:min(9,end))` to get the first 9 characters or all the characters if there are less than 9? Or else use a more explicit condition in your if statement. I think using try for this is a bad idea and damages readability of your code. Please include an example of when you expect this check to fail

Comment: Thank you @Dan, that would be a much nicer way to solve the problem indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `try` have no output value so there is nothing the `if` can use as a condition.

The `try` has its own `if` clause, so

```
try
  % Commands
catch
  % Different commands
end
```

works like *if there is error in `% Commands` then `break` and run `% Different commands`*.

So this code should do the trick:

```
path = 'folder';
listFiles = dir(path);

for ii = 1:length(listFiles)
  try
    strcmp(listFiles(ii).name(1:9), 'file_name')
    % Commands if strcmp does not fail
  catch
    % Commands if strcmp (or any other command) fails
  end
end
```

Comment: So basically what I wanted to do is not possible. Thanks for the reason!

Comment: If my code do exactly what You wanted, then your approach underestimated the powers of `try`. I also recommend `catch ME` to save the error message in `ME` struct.

Comment: I was after a minimalistic and (arguably) elegant way to use a try to set a logical condition, so that is not exactly what I wanted. Thanks anyway, I will read about the `ME` struct!

Comment: This feature is deep inside the `try` and, honestly, I can't imagine different usage than provided by `try` itself.

Comment: All good, honestly @Dan gave a very good remarks in the comments that make these approach pretty much irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
for i = 1:length(listFiles)
try strcmp(listFiles(i).name(1:9), 'file_name')   
    [...] 
catch false,
end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem as it is not algorithmically similar

Comment: Why not ? I don't find place for 'if' there as if  the line after try throws exception next won't be  executed anyway.Then it will throw your flow to catch . Isn't it similar that you wanted. If not you can try following if((try strcmp(listFiles(i).name(1:9), 'file_name')  , catch false, end)==1) not tested but must work.

Comment: `try false, a = 1, catch false, end` this code attribute 1 to a, so it doesn't have any test in it. I wanted to test the condition not just try something.